# UIManagedDocument: How to store additional data like a Thumbnail in an iCloud compatbile way?

Tags: swift, core-data, uimanageddocument

I will be honest with you, I am quite confused on how to store additional content the right way using `UIMangedDocument`. Unfortunately the documentation on `UIMangedDocument` seems to be lacking a lot of information.

I am porting my `UIDocument` based app to a `UIManagedDocument` based app in order to make use of Core Data. In my `UIDocument` based approach I just stored additional data via overriding `contents(forType:)` to return a `FileWrapper`, which contains the appropriate structure and data like a thumbnail.

Now it is my understanding, that in order to store additional data with `UIManagedDocument` you could override `additionalContent(for:)` which needs to return a `Dictionary` or `Data` object. I want this to work with iCloud and Apple mentions in the documentation for `additionalContent(for:)`: "Additional content isn’t supported on iCloud." So this does not seem to be the right approach for me or can this still be used with iCloud?

I could of course store any additional data directly in Core Data's managed object context. But especially in the case of a thumbnail I think this is not the right approach because I would have to create a new `UIMangedDocument`, open it and then fetch the thumbnail from the persistent store every single time I just want to show a thumbnail for the document.

Also using `thumbnailDictionaryKey` and `fileAttributesToWrite(to:for:)` is not the right way as it is deprecated and I want to use the proper new way of a thumbnail extension for showing thumbnails of the documents.

**So, what is the right way to store additional data like thumbnails in a UIManagedDocument in a way that is compatible with iCloud?**